# Any ideas on how to optimize this code? I cant seem to come up with anything that works

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

```
public class SnowflakeWallpaper extends WallpaperService {

// Limit of snowflakes per snowflake type; 4 types * 4 snowflake = 16 total
// Should keep memory usage at a minimal
static int SNOWFLAKE_AMOUNT = 4;
Drawable drawWall;
Rect wallBounds;

// Draw all snowflakes off screen due to not knowing size of canvas at creation
static int SNOW_START = -90;

ArrayList<Snowflakes> snow = new ArrayList<Snowflakes>();
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
 //WallpaperManager to pull current wallpaper
 WallpaperManager wManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
 drawWall = wManager.getFastDrawable();
 wallBounds = drawWall.copyBounds();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new SnowEngine();
}

class SnowEngine extends Engine {

    private final Runnable mDrawSnow = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            drawFrame();
        }
    };

    private boolean mVisible;

    SnowEngine() {  

      if(snow.size() < 16){
     //Back snowflakes
  for(int i = 0; i < SNOWFLAKE_AMOUNT; i++){
   snow.add(new Snowflakes(
     BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
     R.drawable.snowflakeback),
     SNOW_START,
     SNOW_START,
     ((float)(Math.random() * 2) + 1)) // Fall speed initial setup, back slowest to front fastest potentially 
   );
  }

  //MidBack snowflakes
  for(int i = 0; i < SNOWFLAKE_AMOUNT; i++){
   snow.add(new Snowflakes(
     BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
     R.drawable.snowflakemid),
     SNOW_START,
     SNOW_START,
     ((float)(Math.random() * 4) + 1)
   ));
  }

  // Mid snowflakes
  for(int i = 0; i < SNOWFLAKE_AMOUNT; i++){
   snow.add(new Snowflakes(
     BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
     R.drawable.snowflakemidfront),
     SNOW_START,
     SNOW_START,
     ((float)(Math.random() * 8) + 1))
   );
  }
  // Front snowflakes
  for(int i = 0; i < SNOWFLAKE_AMOUNT; i++){
   snow.add(new Snowflakes(
     BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
     R.drawable.snowflake),
     SNOW_START, 
     SNOW_START, 
     ((float)(Math.random() * 16) + 1))
   );
  } 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawSnow);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        mVisible = visible;
        if (visible) {
            drawFrame();
        } else {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawSnow);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int  height) {
        super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
        drawFrame();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
        mVisible = false;
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawSnow);
    }

    /*
     * Update the screen with a new frame
     */
    void drawFrame() {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

        /*
         * if the snow goes too low or too right, reset;
         */
        for(int i = 0; i < snow.size(); i++){
         if(snow.get(i).getX() > holder.getSurfaceFrame().width()){
          snow.get(i).setX(-65);
         }
         if(snow.get(i).getY() > holder.getSurfaceFrame().height()){
          snow.get(i).setY(-69);
         }
        }

        // Test if the array was just create; true - randomly populate snowflakes on screen
        if(snow.get(1).getX() < -70){
         for(int i = 0; i < snow.size(); i++){
          snow.get(i).setX((int)(Math.random() * getSurfaceHolder().getSurfaceFrame().width() +1));
          snow.get(i).setY((int)(Math.random() * getSurfaceHolder().getSurfaceFrame().height() + 1));
         }
        }


        // Change snowflake x & y
        for(int i = 0; i < snow.size(); i++){
         snow.get(i).delta();
        }

        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null) {

                // call to draw new snow position
                drawSnow(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

        // Reschedule the next redraw
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawSnow);
        if (mVisible) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawSnow, 1000 / 100);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Draw the snowflakes
     */
    void drawSnow(Canvas c) {
        c.save();

        // Draw bg
        //********** add code to pull current bg and draw that instead of black. Maybe set this in config?
        if(drawWall == null){
         c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        }else{
         drawWall.copyBounds(wallBounds);
         drawWall.draw(c);
        }

        /*
         * draw up the snow
         */
        for(int i = 0; i < snow.size(); i++){
         c.drawBitmap(snow.get(i).getImage(), snow.get(i).getX(), snow.get(i).getY(), null);
        }

        c.restore();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the problem? Is it too slow? Does it use too much CPU? Does it flicker? Does it even work?

Answer (score 1):

Same question as Gabe - what's the problem?

Some general thoughts:
* You should avoid doing lots of work in a constructor. Your constructor does a ton of work that should (imho) be in some init/setup method instead. Easier to benchmark / profile there independently from instance creation.

- You're using Math.random in many places - I assume you are singly threaded, but Math.random is synchronized. Per the javadocs: " if many threads need to generate pseudorandom numbers at a great rate, it may reduce contention for each thread to have its own pseudorandom-number generator"
- You're using Math.random which gets you a double, then multiplying, then adding, then casting. This looks wasteful. Any way to get fewer ops?
- You seem to have some division - see line "mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawSnow, 1000 / 100);". Sure, that's probably compiled or JIT'd away, but you should avoid division in performance critical code (it's far slower than multiplying). So any div by a constant can be replaced by multiplying by 1 / C as a static.
- You have lots of repeat accessor method calls (in some cases nearly all are repeat). See snippit:

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < snow.size(); i++){
>      if(snow.get(i).getX() > holder.getSurfaceFrame().width()){
>       snow.get(i).setX(-65);
>      }
>      if(snow.get(i).getY() > holder.getSurfaceFrame().height()){
>       snow.get(i).setY(-69);
>      }
>     }
> ```

You should store "holder.getSurfaceFrame().width() in a temporary / local var (perhaps once per draw loop assuming your surface is resizable by the user). You might also store snow.get(i) in a local var. Better yet (style) you can use the enhanced for loop as snow is an ArrayList. So use

```
for (Snow mySnow : snow) {
// Do something with mySnow
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: @Gabe and Noah, it does work, cpu usage seems to be low (haven't done much profiling, still learning, but battery usage according to my droid is between 2 and 3 percent), it seems slow sometimes, but mostly I believe that it is slowing down the UI on the home screen. For example, swiping to the left or right seems to have slowed down. Nothing extremely noticeable but seems laggy sometimes. Ill implement Noahs suggestions and update.